# Button remains active when re-added to DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I've been experiencing a really bizarre issue with *IE9* and *IE10 (Win7 only)*.

If an HTML element (*button, span, anchor*) has an attached click listener which removes itself (or it's container) from the DOM--and then at a later point some other event (e.g: *reset*) adds the element back, the element still remains in ':hover' state, *even without the mouse hovering on the element.*

**WHY** does IE 9 & IE10 (Win7) do this? Also, is there a workaround, without resorting to some *setTimeout* async call?

Take a look at this JSBin: [IE hover/active on remove/add](http://jsbin.com/UNeJuzI/1/edit)

**Code from JSBin**

```
<div id="outer" style="border: 2px solid green; padding: 10px;">
    <div id="container" style="border: 2px solid black; padding: 5px;">
        <button id="button">Hide Me</button>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="reset" style="margin-top: 20px">Reset</button>
```

And the JS:

```
var outer = document.getElementById('outer');
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    outer.removeChild(container);
}, false);

var reset = document.getElementById('reset');
reset.addEventListener('click', function() {
    outer.appendChild(container);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm leaning towards this being a bug in IE were if the element is removed from the DOM the styles aren't being refreshed correctly. However it seems that if you remove the container div as per below the :hover issue is fixed in IE.

I know you said without the use of setTimeout, but I haven't been able to make something else work.

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    outer.removeChild(container);
  }, 1);
}, false);
```

Comment: Yeah for now I implemented a similar async, but it's ugly =( I'll wait a couple days to see if someone can find a cleaner solution otherwise I'll accept yours